# Will companies consider someone for an internship after they graduated?

Tags: internship, canada

I am completing my university degree in Canada and would like to do an internship.

I initially planned to do an internship in during my studies but my immigration status disallowed full-time work until after I graduate. Now, when I view internship postings online, I see that most of them specify the condition that I must be a "student currently enrolled in a Bachelor’s or Master’s degree program" or the like. Note that my degree does not include a PEY/co-op program.

Given that this clause is present on all internship postings that I saw, will companies accept an application from someone who would have graduated by the time they start the internship?

Comment: Could someone clarify the downvotes? I wasn't able to find an answer to this question anywhere else.

Comment: The career advise office at my university did not know the answer to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ask this on the EXPATRIATES site.  Good luck.

Comment: @Fattie A post-graduate work permit will allow me to work _after_ I finish my studies for any company that I want, without restrictions. I was wondering whether employers will hire me despite me having finished my masters, which is why I didn't post this on the EXPATRIATES site.

Comment: fair enough ! good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the company, but some will.

I'm in Canada too, when we graduated from MSC, I went straight into my full time job, while my husband applied to an internship position (because the company was interesting but they had no full time postings). He got hired, but it was framed as contract work for 6 months, after which he got hired on full time.

At my company it wouldn't matter what education you have because interns get specific projects, so as long as you can do that (and you understand that you won't get paid as much), it doesn't really matter what your education level is.

Be sure you disclose relevant facts in your cover letter and explain why you are looking for an internship.

However, if I may offer a piece of advice - just apply for full time work. An internship is typically 8-16 months anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I'de say check with Service Canada first and foremost to see if you are not breaching your visa.

This is a legal matter first and foremost.

Comment: Welcome to Workplace! Thanks for contributing an answer. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Welcome new user!  Great answer.

Comment: @Al rl I have sorted out the legal requirements, but am wondering whether companies will accept an application from someone who would have graduated by the time they start the internship. In fact, I will only be allowed to work _after_ my student visa is finished, which is why I want to see if I can do an internship _after_ I am done studying.